# i ran a speech recognition code but the terminal only show "python -u" ....umm im pretty(very) new to this what does this mean? how do i make it run?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

[heres the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PS6c.png)

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr

def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("start listening", end="")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        query = ''

        try:
            print("processing", end="")
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-US')
            print(f"user said: {query}")

        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception:" + str(e))

    return query.lower()
```

the output i got is python -u what does it mean?

safdsgfdhjtuyrtrsgssuhcaihujhfoihaslljhsfllajsnj

Comment: You have defined a function, but you have not called that function, so this program does nothing at all.  Add `print(takeCommand())` as the last line of your file.